# Why is this extra property allowed on my Typescript object?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

We've recently started using typescript for our web platform projects.

One of the great advantages was supposed to be the powerful typing system, which allows compile-time checks of all kinds of correctness (assuming we put in the effort to model and declare our types properly).

Currently, I seem to have found the limits of what the type system is able to achieve, but it seems inconsistent and I may also just be using wrong syntax.

I'm trying to model the types of objects our app will be receiving from the backend, and to use the type system to have the compiler checks everywhere in the app for:

1. structure, i.e. only existing (enumerated) properties are allowed by the TS compiler on objects of a type
2. property typechecks, i.e. the type of every property is known to the TS compiler

Here is a minimized version of my approach (or take a [direct link to TS playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHA8gIwFYQJgA8AKshAB6QgAmAzsvWFKAOYB8yA3gFDIDkMYBAA2DAFw9+g2QG0A1hACeyUMlIBdKXBCqBAegPIAShGasiyAA5QA9tehhVS5YzB2hoYJCYQwyHYwTCzs9DICAL680bxGyACiIACuALbQGCjOjgDkjKgAQl5itMggcOn0ADRMABZwoqLIOCjJ9BClcIwIdiDMumCMEABu0MoA7rXQEHHGAIK0wwNwbBBSBXClhWUV5s2EcG0oQciiEGyIqrZ2BFYIushgtW37yLXAtLQQIGo-dslQZBwazWZASACU4N45Uq1kQKAAahB3ggztJZFRrHYoAFvmlkAAxETiRh8WSyACydi+TQAvMgAEQAZQA+hSsKgEgAZBlVCLkpnAABeKHpzIAkgAtBIAJgZ-OisXiAGEsCYTAlleQEuq1VIAAr2Rw41QS6VytSMVLAej0di8UCQWDw5BIlFoqg0BhoDDYfCEEhu4CoiAAOiJJXoXDJgmEkakMfJyDkQZD4eJDFDVJp2hCrBAbD5skVvFmyFV6s12t1JgNRqcps9UDgDMtZTsAS6drY5RwZwd4Gg8CQruRwbOMoo1G+3vQmFwt0DY7TEZJ0f5cZJCf5GOozakFntxZipfiADksIka3WHA2pyw4G2QHZxkCEEhrJBaABCAdO4eIsuZwAMz3jO+S+guAbEKmZzppG66yJukjokmyawWGq6ZtmYi5oeBZFmhKZAZhGb0KGgoirmKSpC0UCEUmTZwAeoQFsg8RMrU-ziK8tA2g0ogvh0ADc7YBOoGHwSSFA0b+x6xEAA) )

```
interface DataObject<T extends string> {
    fields: {
        [key in T]: any   // Restrict property keys to finite set of strings
    }
}

// Enumerate type's DB field names, shall be used as constants everywhere
// Advantage: Bad DB names because of legacy project can thus be hidden in our app :))
namespace Vehicle {
    export enum Fields {
        Model = "S_MODEL",
        Size = "SIZE2"
    }
}

// CORRECT ERROR: Property "SIZE2" is missing
interface Vehicle extends DataObject<Vehicle.Fields> {
    fields: {
        [Vehicle.Fields.Model]: string,
    }
}

// CORRECT ERROR: Property "extra" is not assignable
interface Vehicle2 extends DataObject<Vehicle.Fields> {
    fields: {
        extra: string
    }
}

// NO ERROR: Property extra is now accepted!
interface Vehicle3 extends DataObject<Vehicle.Fields> {
    fields: {
        [Vehicle.Fields.Model]: string,
        [Vehicle.Fields.Size]: number,
        extra: string  // Should be disallowed!
    }
}
```

***Why is the third interface declaration not throwing an error, when the compiler seems perfectly able to disallow the invalid property name in the second case?***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. The base interface only specifies what the minimum requirements for `field` are, there is not requirement in typescript for an exact match between the implementing class field and the interface field.  The reason you get an error on `Vehicle2` is not the presence of `extra` but rather that the other fields are missing. (The bottom error is `Property 'S_MODEL' is missing in type '{ extra: string; }'.`)

You can do some type trickery to get an error if those extra properties are present using conditional types:

```
interface DataObject<T extends string, TImplementation extends { fields: any }> {
    fields: Exclude<keyof TImplementation["fields"], T> extends never ? {
        [key in T]: any   // Restrict property keys to finite set of strings
    }: "Extra fields detected in fields implementation:" & Exclude<keyof TImplementation["fields"], T>
}

// Enumerate type's DB field names, shall be used as constants everywhere
// Advantage: Bad DB names because of legacy project can thus be hidden in our app :))
namespace Vehicle {
    export enum Fields {
        Model = "S_MODEL",
        Size = "SIZE2"
    }
}

// Type '{ extra: string; [Vehicle.Fields.Model]: string; [Vehicle.Fields.Size]: number; }' is not assignable to type '"Extra fields detected in fields implementation:" & "extra"'.
interface Vehicle3 extends DataObject<Vehicle.Fields, Vehicle3> {
    fields: {
        [Vehicle.Fields.Model]: string,
        [Vehicle.Fields.Size]: number,
        extra: string // 
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty cool solution IMO. It's a bit hacky and not that easily understandable for non-type-system nerds :D
May I ask where I could learn more about conditonal type checking for example? I think I didn't see any of that in the TS Handbook.

Comment: @MaxAxeHax Um .. don't know for sure. I read the PRs and follow the GitHub project religiously. Also I like to experiment a lot and answering questions here helps me build up my knowledge. There are the official docs but those are pretty narrow in their explanations more of a brief description  of the language feature they do not go into what interesting things you can do with it.

Answer (score 3):

If you imagine that `fields` is an interface like so:

```
interface Fields {
    Model: string;
    Size: number;
}
```

(It's done anonymously, but it does match this interface because of your `[key in Vehicle.Fields]: any`)

Then this fails, because it **doesn't** match that interface - it doesn't have a `Model` or a `Size` property:

```
fields: {
    extra: string
}
```

However, this passes:

```
fields: {
    Model: string;
    Size: number;
    extra: string
}
```

Because the anonymous interface there is an **extension** of your `Fields` interface. It would look something like this:

```
interface ExtendedFields extends Fields {
    extra: string;
}
```

This is all done anonymously through the TypeScript compiler, but you can add properties to an interface and still have it match the interface, just like an extended class is still an instance of the base class

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, it cleared some things up for me. I think I got confused with the case of creating a typed object literal, where the compiler (of course) disallows for the object to add properties which are not part of the declared type.