# Can TypeScript function uses unoin exclusively

Tags: typescript

I am understanding typescript using structural type(duck type),
so following codes are valid

```
interface Teacher {
  age: number
  salary: number
}
interface Student {
  age: number
  classes: string
}

type Person = Teacher | Student

function getAge(person: Person) {
  return person.age
}

getAge({age: 34, salary: 1000}) // ok
getAge({age: 16, classes: '5-4'}) // ok
getAge({age: 20, salary: 1000, classes: '5-4'})  // Should be error but type checker success
```

How to write function signature to prevent
`getAge({age: 20, salary: 1000, classes: '5-4'})`?

Comment: I think [the answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55138283/10345775) may be what you're looking for. Basically, the behavior is expected because TS is structurally typed like you say. You can use conditional types to enforce that extra fields are missing as described there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is this extra property allowed on my Typescript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55137866/why-is-this-extra-property-allowed-on-my-typescript-object)

Comment: thank you for your comment. The link you say is similar to my question but I think it is not general solution . It seems that following question is my case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61960321/typescript-avoid-extra-properties

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at discriminated unions in the typescript documentation.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions

With that, your code should look something like this:

```
interface Teacher {
  kind: 'teacher';
  age: number;
  salary: number;
}
interface Student {
  kind: 'student';
  age: number;
  classes: string;
}

type Person = Teacher | Student;

function getAge(person: Person) {
  return person.age;
}

getAge({ kind:"teacher", age: 34, salary: 1000 }); // ok
getAge({ kind: "student", age: 16, classes: '5-4' }); // ok
getAge({ kind: "teacher", age: 20, salary: 1000, classes: '5-4' }); // now throws error
```